# Drawing image to HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've reviewed the other SO posts and MDN docs, etc on this but still can't figure out why my image is not appearing in the canvas. I appreciate any help on this.

HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="height:500px;width:500px;border:0.5px solid #979797;"></canvas>
```

JavaScript

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/3dItN1Y.png';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rsL3vsju/

Comment: Works for me using a different image https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rsL3vsju/1/

Comment: Changing it to use https doesn't help for me.

Comment: Try to call `drawImage` with two more arguments, the width and the height of the image to be drawn, like so: `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500, 500);` and accordingly set the width and height attributes of the canvas.

Comment: Your css width/height styles will only stretch the canvas view, it doesn't set the canvas view dimensions. Use the html attributes `width="" height=""` (or the properties on the canvas object) to set the dimensions. Due to this the only part of the image you use that is visible is the white surrounding background

Comment: Thank you so much @PatrickEvans! Now I understand whats happening here. I also appreciate the helpful answer from @Vincent!

Comment: @PatrickEvans, post that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting the canvas' height and width with CSS, like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; border: 0.5px solid #979797;"></canvas>
```

That is the wrong code. The correct way is using the `height` and the `width` attributes of the canvas, as below:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="500" width="500" style="border: 0.5px solid #979797;"></canvas>
```